# Optical Character Recognition using Google Drive API

Tags: android, ocr, google-drive-android-api

I am working on an android application. I want to scan a receipt and read the characters, basically do optical character recognition. I read that google drive provides this functionality with their drive APIs & I wish to use Google drive API for this but I am not able to find any tutorial to understand how to achieve this. Can anyone help me with how to start with this.

Thanks

P

Answer (score 0):

There is no tutorial. Images (png, jpg) that you upload to Google Drive (from any app, Android, Web ....) are processed by OCR and indexed by Google. You can test it yourself, just upload a few images that contain text, wait for a while and try to search for words contained in it. Your Android app can use the same facility, but you have to stay with the [RESTful API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/), namely [fulltext](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters) search. AFAIK, this type of search is not yet available in the new [GDAA API](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started).